# Tuples creating a bit of a problem for me

Tags: python, tuples

So , the problem is not in my code , it is in the output .
Also , the problem is stated on Hacker Rank so if you know the solution to it, thanks but I do not need the solution to the original problem , I want my doubt to be cleared.
So the problem is

*You are given a two lists A and B . Your task is to compute their cartesian product X.*

What I have done is ,

```
from itertools import product
list_A = list(map(int ,input().split()))
list_B = list(map(int ,input().split()))
x = list(product(list_A,list_B))
y = tuple(x)
print(y)
```

And this gives me the desired output : `((1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4))`

However , HackerRank doesn't seem to want a tuple . So I need to print out the same values , just not as a tuple .

**Expected Output**    (`1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4)`

I am sure that the solution to this must be pretty simple however I just can not get my head to it for some reason. All help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try printing just the list `print(x)`

Comment: That doesn't work either . It prints a list instead of a tuple. I used a tuple as the section on which I was working was "Tuples"> Thank you anyway.

Comment: Try `print(' '.join([str(z) for z in x]))` to get the string output

Comment: `print(" ".join(f"{x}" for x in y))`

Comment: do `print(*x)`  to pass the list elements as individual arguments to print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.join()` to join a string version of each element with a space character between each:

```py
x = product(list_A, list_B)
print(' '.join([str(t) for t in x]))
```

**Update:**

Also note some of the comments to your question have more direct answers, eg:

```py
print(*product(list_A, list_B))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop and print y one by one with end=' ' in print statement.

```
from itertools import product
list_A = list(map(int ,input().split()))
list_B = list(map(int ,input().split()))
x = list(product(list_A,list_B))
y = tuple(x)
for i in y:
    print(i,end=' ')
```

Comment: I ran this , the output is (1, 3)(1, 4)(2, 3)(2, 4) ; 
Anyway , thank you for your help. The problem has been solved!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to get the values to print out as one line. however, through I used this:

```
for i in range(len(y)):
    print(y[i])
```

to loop through and print level 0 values of the tuple.

Comment: You can use `print([y[i] for i in range(len(y))])`